# No notifications at all on older Facebook Messenger app

Tags: notifications, facebook-messenger

For obvious reasons, I'm using an older version of facebook messenger app (ver 71)

But there are no notifications of arrived message, and important feature

If it's a bug or bad config, can be fixed ?
If not, is there a way to overcome this without third parties ?

Android M
Xperia Z3

Edit:
Tried upgrading to version 81, the last one I can tolerate the bloats, but no change

Tried messing with things like permissions, overlapping, notifications...
Nothing changes

**EDIT:**

It was a bug that went away after reflashing the system.
Unfortunately, I cannot tell what it is

It works now, even for very older (and better) version, like 40.0

The thread may stay open for config speculations

**EDIT 2**

The thing is back again. One day after a master reset it stopped working

I've tried updating to verson 90 (again, not higher, for obvious reasons, but another tolerable version), but no solution

Uninstalling/reinstalling doesn't help

Weird thing is: facebook app notifies it's own alerts, and also when a message arrives on the messenger app.
But android gets no toasts...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [Facebook Messenger Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.mlite) ?

Comment: Thank you man! Didn't know about it.  So much better. Using now. I once tried facebook lite. It was a crap. For that reason I did not look into a lightweight messenger. Thank you again